# Is there a way to tell the length of a UTF-8 encoded string in bytes in C#?

Tags: c#, file-io, utf-8, character-encoding

I wanted to see if there is a way to tell the size, in file size, of a string in .NET.  Imagine you have a sentence of text and a receiving system needs to limit the size of text it receives.

Is there a way to tell the size in bytes or KB of a string or read only the first N bytes or KB of a UTF-8 encoded string?

string testSentence = "I only want the first 2 KB of this sentence.  Is it possible to split this into chunks of 2 KB sequences so I can loop through and send 2 KB at a time to another process?"

Comment: Do you want your 2k chunks split up on character boundaries, or are byte boundaries OK?

Comment: Byte boundaries are ok as long as that doesn't alter the meaning, e.g. not splitting a character.  In the end, I'll convert it to KB, e.g. 2 KB is a real need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the string to bytes using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. Then split the bytes into 2048 byte chunks. Be careful not to split a single character across two chunks.

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testSentence);

int pos = 0;
int length = bytes.Length;

while (length > 0)
{
    int count = 2048;

    if (count >= length) // last chunk
    {
        // send chunk
        Send(bytes, pos, length);
        pos += length;
        length -= length;
    }
    else // not last chunk
    {
        // chop off last character
        while ((bytes[pos + count - 1] & 0xC0) == 0x80) count--;
        count--;
        // send chunk
        Send(bytes, pos, count);
        pos += count;
        length -= count;
    }
}
```

*(untested)*

Comment: Thank you dtb, could you explain this line a little: ((bytes[pos + count - 1] & 0xC0) == 0x80)

Comment: This line checks if the byte has the upper two bits set to 10 (e.g., 10xxxxxx). This means that the byte is part of multiple bytes representing one character. So the code steps back until it finds the first byte of the character and then makes another step back to the last byte of the previous character.

Comment: If you're always going to chop off the last character, why not start off with `count = 2049`?

Comment: The last character is chopped off only in the `else` case, so in the `if` it would send 2049 bytes which doesn't meet the requirement.

Comment: Thanks dtb, that was a good explanation!  Both you and Quintin's answers are pretty darn good.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount().

(Answer edited.)

Answer (score 0):

I think something similar to the following would provide what you are looking for..

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString).Take(2048).ToArray();
```

or

```
byte[] source = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString);
byte[] destination = new byte[2048];
Buffer.BlockCopy(source, 0, destination, 0, 2048);
```

Edit: added example for comment..

This will provide you with a `List<byte[]>` of 2KB chunks, it is worth noting that this is not written for efficiency but rather as example purposes, although it will do the job it is not tuned for high performance.

```
string theString = new string('*', 1022574);

byte[] allData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(theString);
int numberOfChunks = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)(allData.Length) / 2048);
List<byte[]> chunks = new List<byte[]>(numberOfChunks);

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChunks; i++) {
    chunks.Add(allData.Skip(i * 2048).Take(2048).ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Quintin, this seems to get the first 2 KB of data, but how could it get subsequent 2 KB chunks (e.g. get 2 KB at a time of the string then do something else with it like wrap it in other text).

Comment: @AudioFrk I added an example to my answer.